# Should I import a math library, and if so how?

Tags: java, function, math, import, system.out

So I want to print out the math functions, "PI" and "E."

Here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
System.out.println(Math.PI);
System.out.println(Math.E);
```

I think I have to import the math library.

Comment: Did you try compiling this?

Answer (score 3):

`E` and `PI` are not *functions*, they're static [fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#field_summary) (data members). That code will output their values correctly. You don't have to import anything, the `Math` class is in the `java.lang` package, which is imported by default. (It's the only package imported by default, I believe.)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to import anything here. The `java.lang.Math` class should already be available as `java.lang` package is imported by default

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine:

```
/**
   <P>{@code java MathXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class MathXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
     System.out.println(Math.PI);
     System.out.println(Math.E);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java MathXmpl
 3.141592653589793
 2.718281828459045
```

Since `Math` is in the `java.lang` package, it does not need to be imported. `java.lang` is the "default package" and everything in it is already implicitly imported for you.

Comment: If that code works just fine, why do I get this error:

"file not found: null: Java"

Comment: Oh, and on the next line, it says "javac <options> <source files>"

Comment: There is nothing in your question-post that can cause a "file not found" error. You need to provide more information (code!) of exactly what you have tried, if you expect us to be able to help you.

Comment: Copy code above into text file MathXmpl.java. Run `javac MathXmpl.java`. Then run `java MathXmpl`, which executes code in MathXmpl.class

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code. It means your Java runtime cannot find the compiled class!